# Don't fully understand the output of very small C program using void*/char* to refer to and int + pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers

I am having trouble fully understanding why the output of the following code snippet on both onlinegdb.com and visual studio is `2` when I expected a junk/crashed value

I know what little endian and big endian are. My comp clearly should be little endian since it is a 32 bit intel core duo.

I have 512 which in little endian is:

```
0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
^         ^         ^
p         p+1       p+2
```

`p` will point to the first `0000` and `p + 1` to the `0010`. When I print the 2 is from the `0010`, but with `%d` should it not print the decimal representation of `0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 xyzw rstu` (with 8 random bits)?

Q: Did it patch the last bits to 0 by default or was it just luck, took 0 cause they where the last values used? Should it not be undefined?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 512;
    void *p = &x;
    printf("%d\n", *((char*)p + 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your confusion may stem from the fact there is no C/C++ language.  The C and C++ are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::bitset` and smart pointers.  The C language doesn't.  I recommend you pick a single language, C or C++, and update your language tags as appropriate.

Comment: Well you've taken a 32 bit number and interpreted the 2nd set of 8 bytes `0010 0000`..  which is 2 right?  Once reordered as little endian..

Comment: You pass a single char to `printf` (which is then promoted to int, as integral promotion goes, but retains its value of 2).

Comment: You should use `uint8_t *` instead of `void *`.  Cast as appropriate when initializing.

Comment: Endianness doesn't reorder nybbles, it reorders bytes. So 512 as a little endian 32-bit number is `{0, 2, 0, 0}`. The value 2 is taken from the second byte, and implicitly converted to an `int` before being passed to `printf`.

Comment: If you're expecting to print a garbage string you will have to change your format specifier to %s instead of printing your int reinterpreted as a char and then promoted back to an int when using the %d format specifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With `%d` should it not print 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 xyzw rstu (8 random bits)?

No, not in your case.

You are doing this:

```
*((char*)p + 1)
```

Which means the following:

1. Take `p` and cast it to `char *`.
2. Advance 1 position (casted to `char *` means 1 byte).
3. Dereference that (still as `char *`), obtaining 1 byte.
4. The byte you obtain is 2.
5. The byte gets now implicitly converted to an `int` when passed to `printf`.

In other words, this is what happens:

```
0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
          ^^^^^^^^^
          (char*)p+1
          vvvvvvvvv
          0100 0000 [0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000]
                     promotion to int when calling printf
```

So this is why you don't see "8 random bits".

---

On the other hand, if instead you were to do something like this:

```
// notice the second cast to (int*) AFTER advancing 1 byte
printf("%d\n", *(int*)((char*)p + 1));
```

Then this would have been *undefined behavior*. You *could* have seen some random bits (which means a much bigger value), or you could have gotten zeroes out of luck, but since it's UB you cannot really expect anything meaningful from it.

Answer (score 4):

> I have 512 which in little endian is:
> 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Correct, except it is actually 0000 0000 0000 0010. Endianess is *byte* order, not nibble order.

> p + 1 to the 0010

Correct, it points at the *byte* 0000 0010.

> When i print the 2 is from the 0010, but with %d should it not print 0010 0000 ...

No, because when you de-reference the 8 bit `char` you end with a value 2 inside a 8 bit temporary object.

And as it turns out, variadic functions such a `printf` promote small integer parameters to `int` (*default argument promotions*), regardless of the format specifiers. So you end up with an `int` with value `2` and then `printf` prints that value.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make a *copy* of the byte before printing it:

```
int main()
{
    const int x = 512;
    uint8_t * p = (uint8_t *)(&x);
    for (unsigned int i = 0u; i < sizeof(int); ++i)
    {
        const uint8_t value = *p++;
        printf("%d\n", value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Making a copy of the memory into a variable prevents the compiler from interpreting the location equation as a 4 byte integer (as in your example).